# Android: Animation always settling at the center

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

This is my slide animation.

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="-30%p" />
```

The slide is fine. But the view always finally settles at the center of the screen. Is there any problem with the above code?

Thanks,
Rahul.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta set the attribute [fillAfter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android%3afillAfter) to "true".

**Code:**

```
animation.setFillEnabled(true);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

**XML:**

```
<set
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="-30%p" />

</set>
```

Hope that helps!